# How do I copy a row in joined tables in postgesql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

For example I have two tables main_table and ref_table which are joined on primary key of main table :

```
create table table main (
    id serial primary key,
    name varchar(100)
);

create table table_ref (
    main_id bigint references table_main(id),
    vals varchar(100)
);
```

What I want to do is to copy row in both tables based on id. When I do it like this it works, but I can't understand how to copy vals column from table_ref:

```
with copy_main as (
    insert into table_main (name)
        select name 
        from table_main inner join
             table_ref
             on id=main_id
             where id=1
        returning id, 'I need vals from table_ref here!!!' as vals
       )
insert into table_ref (main_id, vals)
    select id, vals
    from copy_main;
```

How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
with copy_main as (
    insert into table_main (name)
        select m.name 
        from table_main m
        where m.id = 1
        returning id
       )
insert into table_ref (main_id, vals)
    select cm.id, r.vals
    from copy_main cm cross join
         table_ref r
    where r.main_id = 1;
```

Comment: need to add m.id=1 in first select also, after it works fine